# Can't figure out how to link multiple nesting many to many relationships

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm setting up a user authentication modules to specify three roles: 'r', 'w', 'x', however I can't figure out how to link all the subcomponents of the website. The website has five levels: 1- Multiple organization 2-Each organization has a number of projects 3-Each project has a number of modules. The user permissions should be linked to the module of the project of the organization.

This is using flask sqlalchmey and flask-migrate. I've read through both flask sqlalchemy, and sqlalchemy.com documentation and found association tables to be potentially what can solve the problem. But I'm stuck here,

```
class Hospital(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'hospitals'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True)


class Project(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'projects'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True)


class Module(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'modules'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True)


class HospitalProject(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'hospital_projects'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    hospital_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('hospitals.id'), primary_key=True)
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id'), primary_key=True)
    hospital = db.relationship('Hospital', backref='projects')
    project = db.relationship('Project', backref='hospitals')


class HospitalProjectModules(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'hospital_project_modules'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True)
    hospital_project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('hospital_projects.id'), primary_key=True)
    module_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('modules.id'), primary_key=True)
    hospital_project = db.relationship('HospitalProject', backref='modules')
    module = db.relationship('Module', backref='hospital_projects')


class Role(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True)


class HospitalProjectModulesUserRoles(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'hospital_project_modules_user_roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    hospital_project_module_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('hospital_project_modules.id'), primary_key=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    hospital_project_module = db.relationship('HospitalProjectModules', backref='User_Roles')
    user = db.relationship('User', backref='hospital_project_module_roles')
    role = db.relationship('Role', backref='hospital_project_module_users')
```

I'm running into this error. I know this is because hospital_projects doesn't have a unique identifier but I can't figure out how to solve it.

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidForeignKey) there is no unique constraint matching given keys for
referenced table "hospital_projects"

```
[SQL:
CREATE TABLE hospital_project_modules (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR,
        hospital_project_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        module_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id, hospital_project_id, module_id),
        FOREIGN KEY(hospital_project_id) REFERENCES hospital_projects (id),
        FOREIGN KEY(module_id) REFERENCES modules (id),
        UNIQUE (name)

app/models.py61:51
LFUTF-8Pythongit+
DAMPublishGitHubGit (8)2 updates
```

Answer (score 1):

You have PrimaryKey constraints on all your Foreign Key Reference columns.
Remove these constraints as they are unnecessary because you have setup each Table to have its own 'id' field as the primary key.
Basically, in your code above each of your tables should only have a single PrimaryKey Column.

e.g.
`hospital_project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('hospital_projects.id'), primary_key=True)`
becomes
`hospital_project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('hospital_projects.id'))`